# How can I solve the system of ODEs $x'=-5x+10y, y'=-4x+7y, z'=z^2-2z+1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

How can I solve the following system of differential equations?

$$\begin{aligned} x' &= -5x + 10y\\ y' &= -4x + 7y\\ z' &= z^2 -2z + 1\end{aligned}$$

I have to give a function $f(x)$, that $f(0)=(1,0,2)$. I don't know how to manage the problem with the variable $z^2$.

Could you also tell me what the maximum interval of definition of $f(x)$ is?

Comment: Yes i though of solving first z' = z^2 -2z +1, in an isolated way but i don't know how to solve this differential equation. Is it a Ricatti type?

Comment: Could you be more specific? I don't understand what you mean. Thank very much

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%28u-1%29%5E2).

Comment: I have resolved it. Thank you very much. I didn't realised that z'=(z-1)^2

Comment: And if my equation was z' = z^3 -2z +1, what could i do in this case?

Comment: Partial fraction expansion.

Comment: And how can I expand 1/(z^3-2*z+1)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fraction+decomposition+of+1%2F%28z%5E3+-+2*z+%2B+1%29).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{dz}{dt}=z^2-2z+1 \implies \int \frac{dz}{(z-1)^2}=\int dt \implies \frac{1}{1-z}=t+C$$
The coupled equation for $x,y$ can be solved by matrix method to get $$x(t)=e^{t}(C_1 \sin 2t+ C_2 \cos 2t),$$ where $1\pm 2i$ are the eigenvalues of the matrix. Putting it in the first equation one can get $y(t)$. Next $C_1,C_2$ can be determined by the conditions such as $x(t_0)=x_0, y(t_0)=y_0$